# Writing a test methods for code written by someone else

Tags: unit-testing

I have a some piece of code and I need to write a test methods for it.

For example: there is an Open method that opens a file. But there is no code inside that throws FileNotFOundException. If I put bad file name, it will produce COMException. Now should I do test for catching COMException, or should I make test for catching FileNotFoundException? Ofcourse test will fail. I dont understand how to build test in this direction. Test driven development looks logic, but how to do it in reverse?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think you should be tailoring your tests for the code you have - I think you should be testing for your  required use cases. What conditions should your code succeed under and under which conditions should it fail and what should it do. Once you know these then write the test code and run your unit tests.

In the example you've stated - if the file will always be present then I see no reason to check for a file not found, however if the file could sometimes not appear - what should happen (don't look at the code - look at the requirements), and write a test to verify that that actually happens.

Of course you may find that the code fails many test that cover it's use cases - this is where you then manage the discrepancies.

Answer (score 0):

I would say you should test for both and see if you can somehow make that code get changed to return a FileNotFoundException.